# Speed up BOW/LINEAR animation in Here map sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I am working with Here map sdk in android. I have applied Bow animation for centering markers and for all other things. When i compare it to ios code it is slower than ios. 
How can i make this inbuild animations of here map faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the SDK APIs do not allow you to control the speed of the pre-defined animations.

Comment: yeah i have searched everywhere. its not in our control. Thanks for your answers. Somehow my lead needs that dont know how to explain them :D

Comment: Write your own animation engine on top of the Map APIs. If you use basic bezier curves you can animate much nicer than the default BOW or LINEAR animations.

Comment: @davidLeong : Can u send me any link which will be helpful to implement because what you said is new to me

Comment: @djk did you ever come up with a way to customize animation easing and speed?

Comment: @GregEnnis no i never able to implement it. sorry